# what does Java Volatile Read really do?

Tags: java, atomic, volatile, lock-free, java-memory-model

I have a very confused question about java volatile read.

I will show two cases to explain my question.

case1:

```java
class TestVolatile {
    public boolean running = true;
    public volatile boolean volatileField;

    void run() {
        while(running) {
        }
        System.out.println("stopped.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TestVolatile t = new TestVolatile ();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(t::run, "t1");
        t1.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        t.running = false;
        t1.join();
    }
}
```

case1 won't stop, This is completely understandable because running is not volatile.

Next I will show the second case.

case2:

```java
class TestVolatile {
    public boolean running = true;
    public volatile boolean volatileField;

    void run() {
        while(running) {
            // just add a volatile read, the code will stop . 
            if (volatileField) {
                
            }
        }
        System.out.println("stopped.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TestVolatile t = new TestVolatile ();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(t::run, "t1");
        t1.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        t.running = false;
        t1.join();
    }
}
```

**just as case2 shows, after add a volatile read in the while loop, the code will stop.**

so, why? running is not a volatile field and the code does not write volatileField.
is there some happen-before relation can explain case2? thanks a lot for any help!

From the perspective of JMM, why? From the perspective of native code, why?

I have added ** -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:CompileCommand=print,*TestVolatile.run -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=intel ** to jvm option to see native code of TestVolatile.run. But I don't see any special instruction about the volatile read.

my runtime:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

macOS catalina 10.15.5
2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
```

Comment: The fact that "running" is not volatile doesn't mean that "t1" will never see its value set by another thread,, it simply means that the JVM takes the liberty to optimize the code and not synchronizing the threads memory right after the set happens. But such synchronization will occur eventually, and you are forcing it by reading a volatile value (even though is not set). But again, you would end up reading it anyway, if you set a long timeout in your case 1, you may happen to stop as well (simply not at the right time)

Comment: I suggest you to read [this guide about volatile](https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile), I find it simple and pretty explanatory.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: *But such synchronization will occur eventually,* -- not necessarily; I'm pretty sure lack of `volatile` lets a JVM hoist a load out of the loop when making asm (like in C++ with a non-`atomic` int, where that would be undefined behaviour).  So the compiler / runtime can effectively transform `while(running)` into `if(running) while(42){}` when JITing.  The reason a volatile read matters is that it may synchronize with another thread, which would trigger language rules about being able to see values, and thus require a load in the asm.

Comment: @Matteo NNZ yes, you are right,  thanks. But I still want to know why reading a volatile value will make another non-volatile filed be synchronized ?Does JMM guarantee this？ someone told me that the reason is "running" share same cache line with "volatileField" , but after I add enough padding(>= 128 bytes) between "running" and "volatileField", the code still stop.

Comment: @JackLiu: Nothing to do with cache line boundaries; this is a JIT-compile-time effect.  yshavit's answer is correct (and agrees with my previous comment.)  And no, I don't Matteo is correct.  If the loop was checking the value at all, would see the store in tens of nanoseconds after another thread executes it, if you run this on a normal x86 system like yours.  The fact that it doesn't means there's most likely no check at all inside the loop the JIT compiler produced.

Comment: @JackLiu the technical reason is explained in the answer you received. Declaring the field volatile makes the JVM respect an order of before/after, making your case 2's thread 1 memory having the same state of the main thread's memory (so it will see running = false), whereas in case 1, the synchronization of running = false in the cache of thread 1 may happen later and so you don't see it on time

Comment: @MatteoNNZ:  Related: https://software.rajivprab.com/2018/04/29/myths-programmers-believe-about-cpu-caches/ - cache is coherent on all hardware we run threads across.  The kind of "caching" that breaks code is when *compilers* choose to keep values in registers, not the CPU cache itself being stale.  If synchronization didn't happen in a hundred nanoseconds (in low contention conditions like this), it's not going to happen at all, unless the JVM discards the JIT optimized asm for some reason and happens to go back to interpreting naively for some iterations.

Comment: @PeterCordes while I agree with you on the pure theory, I posted my comment in the light of any JVM implementation that I've ever used which always end up at some point flushing memory from the Ram to caches (for example at garbage collection). But it's not the theoretical answer, I agree, that's why I posted it as a comment

Comment: @PeterCordes My original answers was actually a bit incorrect, in that it incorrectly implied that a HB-edge is what's publishing the data. There's no write to the volatile field (other than its default value), so there isn't actually a HB. The JMM is just translating the read to a cache flush, which is a superset of the required semantics.

Comment: @yshavit: Yeah, it doesn't *actually* sync with anything, the JIT just makes code that would work if it did.  That implies a JIT compiler can't assume values of other variables stay the same across a volatile read, that it works like a compiler barrier. (That's why I was saying in the first place, and I assume what your answer was intended to imply.  But yeah not a bad idea to make it explicit.) C and C++ compilers also don't try to optimize according to what other threads could actually be doing in the program, they make asm that works with any hypothetical other thread that follows the rules

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: No idea what you mean by "flushing data from the RAM to the caches"; if anything needed to get flushed it would be the cache getting flushed to RAM.  But it doesn't, actual CPU cache is coherent.  Interesting point that GC could make a loop not quite infinite; you're right, hotspot does load a pointer and deref it inside the loop, and a couple times per second that segfaults (SIGSEGV) which I guess it catches as a way to get notified of GC happening.  But despite that, this program is so simple that GC isn't moving `running` so it doesn't get re-read.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: There's no timeout in this code.  The sleep is to give the reader thread time to get JIT optimized before the store.  I left it running for over 3 minutes, and as I expected it doesn't exit.  (OpenJDK 11.0.13 on x86-64).  (I changed the Sleep to a `for(int i=0 ; i<1000000000 ; i++){}` since my javac didn't have that library I guess.)  Perhaps a non-toy program that does generate some GC churn would be different.  Of course the language standard doesn't rule out re-reading anything at any time; the important thing as we both agree is the lack of guarantee of prompt reading.

Comment: @PeterCordes I quickly ran the same test on openjdk 11.0.2-BellSoft on x86-64, and it exits after 450ms :) I don't know the reason, I think it's really related to the JVM specific implementation. But again, I agree with you on the theory, you can disregard all my comments cause unfortunately now I don't have time to explain better what I meant plus comments are not very fit for that :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: 450ms after executing `t.running = false;`?  Or 450ms total, so probably nanoseconds after finishing my delay loop and running the store?  (The latter would mean that the `t1` loop is checking `running` every time, not hoisting the load).  I don't know what BellSoft is; I don't normally do much with Java.

Answer (score 4):

Reading a volatile field doesn't only ensure you see the most up-to-date version of it. It also establishes a formal [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) relationship: any write to the field happens-before a subsequent read to it. That happens-before means the reading thread sees at least the same state *of the full program* as the writing thread saw at the time of the write. That's what's causing the reading thread to see the non-volatile write.

These same semantics are what also let you publish non-thread-safe objects across threads, as long as they're not modified after they're published. And they're the same semantics that various thread-safe collections create, as described in the docs for [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Now, in your code, you don't actually write to `volatileField` after setting `running` to false. So, where is the happens-before edge come from? Actually -- nowhere! You still have a data race, and the JVM doesn't have to show you the most recent version of `running`. But many JVM implementations just treat a volatile read as "okay, let's flush all the core caches to make sure this thread sees everything," and you're benefiting from that behavior. A JVM with a more stingy and precise application of the JMM could break your code.

Comment: I think you are right, but I don't see any evidence to prove it. I have add  `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:CompileCommand=print,*TestVolatile.run -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=intel` to jvm option to see native code of TestVolatile.run. But I don'e see any special instruction about the volatile read.

on x86-64, I know when write volatile field, jvm all add `lock add DWORD PTR [rsp],0x0` to set memory barrier, but when read volatile field, I don't see anything like this.

Comment: the native of reading volatile field is just this:
```
0x00000001137cfe83: nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
0x00000001137cfe88: movsx  edx,BYTE PTR [rsi+0xd]  ;*getfield volatileField
    ; - cpucache.TestVolatile::run@8 (line 504)
```

Comment: Why not append the assembly code to have a check together?

Comment: A proper synchronized Java program should be sequential consistent (SC). For SC the real-time order doesn't matter and that implies that a read doesn't need to see the most recent write; reads and writes can be skewed as long as program-order isn't violated. Linearizability is SC + respecting real-time order.

Comment: Thinking in terms of cache flushing is an invalid mental model. This is not how CPUs work. CPU caches are always coherent on modern CPUs; memory is just a spill bucket for whatever doesn't fit in the cache. https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-commit-semantics

Comment: @pveentjer Your point about the SC is correct, but the OP's code (even the second one) doesn't actually have a HB edge, so the behavior they're seeing isn't guaranteed. As to the real-time-ness, you're again correct — but in practice, people expect (and JVMs uphold) a "very fast, basically right away" visibility. True, that's not actually required by the spec, that's not necessary a useful observation. "Run one instruction, pause for 10 years, and then the rest" is also a valid SC ordering, but everyone would agree it's buggy. Same with a too-long skew of volatile reads.